# Integrating Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2010 (Power Tools) check-in policy issue

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Currently we have setup TFS 2010 on build machine and using Visual Studio 2010 for development. We have included following check-in policies using TFS 2010 power tools :

1. Changeset Comments Policy
2. WorkItems
3. Forbidden Patterns Policy

And Forbidden Patterns Policy has the following regular expressions
[image]

We have started working on Visual Studio 2013 (VS 2010 and VS 2013 has been installed side-by-side) in addition i have installed VS 2013 on build machine including TFS power tools 2013 and integrated it with TFS 2010.

During each tfs activity (check-in, View history, etc ) i am getting the following message from VS 2013 every time:

[image]

I have tried removing check-in policies from VS 2010 as well as from VS 2013, when i view the history or perform check-in under VS 2013 i am getting above mentioned error.